# Activating Windows on a VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-activation, virtual-desktop

I am working with Windows Server 2008 running on Virtual Desktop to develop SharePoint applications... I keep getting messages about Windows not being able to activate because the 'DNS name does not exist'.  Now since I don't want to redo any sharepoint setup if this causes problems down the line, I'd like to know the following:

1)  Can I continue using my valid copy of Windows Server indefinitely without completing the activation process?

2)  What is causing this DNS error, and how do I fix it if I do need to finish the activation process?

3)  What are best practices for Windows activation if you want to develop on many virtual machines created from the same CD/key... should I have distinct copies of Windows for each VM?   Does Microsoft have some kind of licensing mechanism for temporary machines used for development only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary machines can be run in the grace period, which can be extended (KB 948472), if you're willing to live with it annoying you.  Otherwise you're eventually going to run out of activations (MAK style volume key or retail key) or need to have enough machines in the organization (KMS key).  Grace is basically the short-term evaluation solution.  Alternatively, you could actually use the 180 day evaluation version, downloadable from Microsoft.

Windows Server 2008 Standard lets you run one virtual instance if the host is for running VMs only.  Windows Server 2008 Enterprise includes up to four virtual instances in the license.  I'm assuming Enterprise is the highest license you have as if you have Datacenter you know all about this stuff.  (ref: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx#virt)

Answer (score 0):

you can activate windows via telephone.

and legally you can use only one installation (virtual or otherwise) per license at the same time.